# Receive only one data from filters to struct

Tags: swift, struct, filter, swift3

Short question, I have the following structure, which I store in "Salas"

```
struct SalasMaster {
    let id: Int
    let nombre: String
    let latitud: String
    let longitud: String
    let piso: String
    let observaciones: String
    let pabellon: String
}

var Salas = [SalasMaster]()

...receiving data...
...dump(Salas)
        example -> SalasMaster
                   - id: 307
                   - nombre: "SALA DE PROYECTOS "
                   - latitud: "-29.96429300"
                   - longitud: "-71.34937300"
                   - piso: "1"
                   - observaciones: ""
                   - pabellon: "X - Escuela de Ingeniería"
```

And finally what I want is to filter the example id, at this moment I get an array where it is, along with all other corresponding data

```
...filter data...

var arrayFiltered = Salas.filter{$0.id == 307}

Print(arrayFiltered) -> [SalasMaster(id: 307, nombre: "SALA DE PROYECTOS ", latitud: "-29.96429300", longitud: "-71.34937300", piso: "1", observaciones: "", pabellon: "X - Escuela de Ingeniería")]
```

But I can't find the way to return only one data that I'm interested in retrieving from "id", in this case I want to capture only "latitud", although in another case I might need another one.

Comment: So you would like to filter `Salas` by id or maybe something else, and then return a list of the `latitud`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1848165-first) for that because it will give you first matching record and stop searching after it.

```
if let sale = Salas.first(where: { $0.id == 307 }) {
    print(sale.latitud)
}
```

Comment: For the id search case it also seems like a very efficient idea :) I will also need it. Thank you!

Comment: Well, regarding my question, you're right, apologies!

Comment: @DiegoSalinasFlores No need to apologies mate. I'm just confirming your question thats it, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This will map through `Salas` and return an array of `latitud`s.

```
Salas.flatMap { $0.id == 307 ? $0.latitud : nil }
```

***For example***

```
var arrayFiltered = Salas.flatMap { $0.id == 307 ? $0.latitud : nil }

Print(arrayFiltered) -> ["-29.96429300"]
```

Comment: interesting solution but something inefficient because it is going to iterate all the array even founding the desired one, ideally it should stop the iteration once the desired item is found.

Comment: I needed this! Throughout the app I need to make multiple filters at the same time as well, so I need to go through the entire array "Salas". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct SalasMaster {
  let id: Int
  let nombre: String
  let latitud: String
}

// creating the array
let sala1 = SalasMaster(id: 1, nombre: "Sala1", latitud: "123")
let sala2 = SalasMaster(id: 2, nombre: "Sala2", latitud: "321")
let salas = [sala1, sala2]

let idToFind = 1
let latitudFound = salas
                        .first { $0.id == idToFind } // returns the object found
                        .map   { $0.latitud } // we transform the object

if let latitudFound = latitudFound {
  print(latitudFound) // 123
}
```

or if you want to get more than one field that interests you, you could use **tuples**:

```
let idToFind = 1
let salaFound = salas
                     .first { $0.id == idToFind } // returns the object found
                     .map   { (latitud: $0.id, nombre: $0.nombre) } // returns a tuple

if let sala = salaFound {
  print(sala.latitud) // 123
  print(sala.nombre) // Sala1
  //print(sala.id) // (latitud: Int, nombre: String) has no member 'id'
}
```

Comment: In essence is quite similar to the Nirav D answer, but I might need to save the tuple directly with your code :) thanks!