# How to return the element that contains the searched for element

Tags: arrays, swift3

I have 2 classes:

```
- Favourite
    + key
    + showKey
 - Show
    + key
```

I have an array of `favouriteShows` `[Favourite]`
I have a show object `show`

To check if the show's key is part of favouriteShows I do:

```
if favouriteShows.contains(where: {$0.showKey == show.key}) {
...
}
```

But I also want to identify which favourite it was that had the showKey.

Something like `let favouriteIndex = favouriteShows.contains(where: {$0.showKey == show.key})`

Comment: You can even use `first(where:)` like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42037292/6433023 to get the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index)

```
guard let favouriteIndex = favouriteShows.index(where: {$0.showKey == show.key}) else {
    // no favourite matched
    return
}

// use favouriteIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can enumerate the `favouriteShows` array as follows:

```
for (ndx, sh) in favouriteShows.enumerated() {
    if sh.showKey == show.key {
        // ndx contains the index at this point
    }
}
```